# Strategies to use with boost::geometry::union_

Tags: c++, boost-geometry

boost::geometry::union_() takes an optional "strategy" argument, which is described as "Any type fulfilling a Union_ Strategy Concept". I'm interested in learning if there's an existing strategy that can help me with a particular problem I'm having. Here's some code:

```
using point_t = boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double>;
using polygon_t = boost::geometry::model::polygon<point_t>;
using mpolygon_t = boost::geometry::model::multi_polygon<polygon_t>;

polygon_t obstacle1{{{-2, 7},
                     {2, 7},
                     {2, 3},
                     {-2, 3},
                     {-2, 7}}};

polygon_t obstacle2{{{-2.8284271247461903, 5},
                     {0, 7.82842712474619},
                     {2.8284271247461903, 5},
                     {0, 2.1715728752538097},
                     {-2.8284271247461903, 5}}};

polygon_t obstacle3{{{0.75, 3.0},
                     {0.75, 2.4215728752538097},
                     {0.2, 2.4215728752538097},
                     {0.75, 3.0}}};
mpolygon_t obstacles{obstacle1, obstacle2, obstacle3};

mpolygon_t consolidated;
for (auto const& obstacle : obstacles) {
    if (boost::geometry::overlaps(obstacle, consolidated)) {
        mpolygon_t temp;
        boost::geometry::union_(obstacle, consolidated, temp);
        consolidated = std::move(temp);
    } else {
        consolidated.push_back(obstacle);
    }
}
```

I would expect that the vertices resulting from the union of `obstacle2` and `obstacle3` would be collinear with the appropriate edge of `obstacle2`. I'm finding that they're around 1e-7 off, which is a bigger error than I'd expect (the underlying coordinate type is `double`, after all).

So, is there a strategy that I can supply which will reduce the error I'm seeing?

Comment: By haphazard experimentation, I've learned that `bg::strategy::intersection::cartesian_segments<>` is not the answer I'm hoping for.

Comment: Boost (as of 1.70) doesn't provide union strategies. In [reference page](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference_alphabetical_index.html), other algos have the list of applicable strategies after their entry. Looking into the code, the default_strategy is a placeholder. Do you expect someone to propose a new strategy ?

Comment: @MichaelDoubez What I'm trying to learn is if there is an existing strategy for bg::union_() that synthesizes vertices that are closer than 1e-7 to each of the edges that intersect. If there is not, that's good to know. I'm painfully aware that my use of boost::geometry seems to be atypical.

Comment: Have you checked if compilation generate any narrowing or loose-of-data warnings ?

Comment: @darune No warnings whatsoever, with "-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors"